# Discord app error R10 when deploying with Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I tried to deploy my discord bot made with Node.js to Heroku, the build is successful but the app crashes and throws an error:

```
Error R10 (Boot timeout)
Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

My `Procfile`:

```
web: node app.js
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "bot",
  "version": "5.0",
  "description": "Discord Bot",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "me",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.3.2",
    "ffmpeg-binaries": "^3.2.2-3",
  }
}
```

My app takes a few seconds to launch localy.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That's caused by the fact that you're not building a website, but your dyno is set to `web`.
You can change your dyno type in your `Procfile` by replacing `web` with `worker`:

```
worker: node app.js
```

Make sure this new `worker` dyno is active by going to your [Heroku app dashboard](https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps) > your app > resources (you can use the pencil buttons to turn on/off dynos)

Comment: Oh my god you saved me hours of searching... It's so stupid that it doesn't provide the worker I provide and STILL USES THE WEB ONE.

Comment: @mohkamfer Happy to hear that ^_^