# Discord bot goes down when closing the console

Tags: heroku

I hosted my bot on Heroku and I set all the configs (worker, token...)
When I try to turn it on I'm forced to use the console but, when I close it after typing the `node index` command, the bot goes offline.

App logs:

```
2019-04-21T11:52:21.580110+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-21T11:52:21.423708+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: Awaiting client
2019-04-21T11:52:21.721889+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: Starting process with command `node index`
2019-04-21T11:52:24.425348+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: Client connection closed. Sending SIGHUP to all processes
2019-04-21T11:52:24.962968+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: State changed from up to complete
2019-04-21T11:52:24.944749+00:00 heroku[run.9063]: Process exited with status 129
```

Comment: "so when i try to make it alive i m forced to use the console"—why? And exactly how are you starting it?

Comment: cause i need to make the bot alive ..

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Why do you think you need to use the console to do that?

Comment: And, _again_, exactly how are you starting it?

Comment: Just from a Google search, [here's a guide on hosting a D.js bot on Heroku](https://github.com/synicalsyntax/discord.js-heroku). Are you following this setup? You shouldn't be using the `node` command to start the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bot goes offline because if you start it from the console the process is "bound" to that window: closing that window will also close the process.

To avoid these problems you can try making your dyno start the bot:

- Go into your `Procfile` file and add the command you use to start the bot (both `node` and `npm` work) to your `worker`.
  If you don't know that the `Procifile` is, please take a look at [this article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile).
  When you're done it should look something like this:

```
worker: node index
```

- After that commit `Procfile` to your repo and push it to Heroku: you should see your dyno type in the "Resources" tab of your app. Make your that the dyno type you just added is the only active one.
  ([*Why do I need to use the `worker` dyno?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51985448/7133466))

From now on, every time your app is deployed Heroku will run the command you entered as soon as the dyno is loaded. If you want to see the logs of your app you can either use *"More" menu > View logs* or, if you have the Heroku CLI installed on your computer, the following command:

```
heroku logs -a your-app-name-here --tail
```